# Azure clean $web before deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Im trying to set a proper release pipeline of my static web app onto Azure Blob Storage

I have created Azure CLI step in pipeline which would clean the $web container on Azure Blob Storage so that everytime I copy files in the next step I will copy them into a fresh clean container (there wont be leftovers from previous releases)

So here is the code for Azure CLI task:

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <storage account> --source "\$web" --account-key <KEY>
```

However on this task when I check the logs it fails and gives the following error:

```
2021-04-21T14:16:22.5684170Z [command]C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1619014555799.ps1'"
2021-04-21T14:17:31.5066809Z ERROR: Client-Request-ID=*** Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Wed, 21 Apr 2021 14:17:30 GMT, Server-Request-ID=***, HTTP status code=200, Exception='NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'.
2021-04-21T14:17:31.5150108Z ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'
2021-04-21T14:17:32.1520724Z ##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
```

What might be causing this error?

Comment: When I execute the command you're using in bash terminal, it works just fine. I am wondering if it has something to do with `$` sign? May be it is not being properly escaped. Can you try with some other dummy container (just to validate this hypothesis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no issue with your command try checking with another container.

check link
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/az-storage-blob-delete-batch-command-in-azure-devo/1191011

Comment: Hi Alex, What is this result when you try with a different container in different resource group as lavanya mentioned thread?

Comment: this worked, seems to be bug on the side of Azure

Answer (score 0):

I've have the exact same issue today, wondering if you managed to get around. I think as a work around I might need to use Powershell to loop through and delete the objects individually.

Comment: I created new container from scratch and it worked.

Comment: Great, thank you. Not ideal but it is what it is until MS address it I guess!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been stuck on this issue and I discovered the solution in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=bash%2Cbash2

The excerpt that helped me solve this issue:

> There are special characters of PowerShell, such as at @. To run Azure CLI in PowerShell, add ` before the special character to escape it. You can also enclose the value in single or double quotes "/".

Below are both methods suggested in the documentation using OPs original command.

**1. Using Quotations:**

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <storage account> --source ""$"web" --account-key <KEY>
```

**2. Using Tick Mark**

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name <storage account> --source "`$web" --account-key <KEY>
```